# Why does my FPS go down so much when rendering basic sprites?

Tags: rendering, directx11, frame-rate

I have a UWP DX11 application and I've recently removed the vsync and noticed that my fps goes down drastically when I'm only drawing very basic sprites on the screen and I'm trying to learn why this is so I can improve it. I would *not* expect it to drop this low for only rendering sprites.

With only a single sprite drawing on the screen, and everything still present in the update loop I am getting around ~3000 fps which is what I would expect for my graphics card.

However, there is a huge drop when I'm only rendering the projectiles on the screen.
[image]

Just from rendering these projectiles I dropped from around ~3000 fps to ~500 which is an absurd amount when they are so small in size. When I render the other entities on the screen with no projectiles, I am dropping to around ~200.

The fact I can run modern 3d games at a higher fps than I can render about ~20 sprites on my screen proves I am doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what. Could anyone provide any points as to why this might be?

If there is any additional information required I can gladly assist, I just don't know what code is required for this type of issue.

---

```
void Update()
{
    m_timer.Tick([&]()
    {
        //update keypresses
        m_keybindManager->Update(m_timer);

        //update player
        m_player->Update(m_timer);

        //update projectiles
        m_projectileManager->Update(m_timer);

        uint32 fps = m_timer.GetFramesPerSecond();
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "FPS: " << fps << "\n" << std::endl;
        OutputDebugStringA(ss.str().c_str());

    });
}

bool Render()
{
    if (m_timer.GetFrameCount() == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    SpriteRenderer* renderer = m_spriteRenderer.get();

    //set up the renderer before drawing
    renderer->InitializeRenderer();

    //draw player
    Sprite& s = m_player->GetSprite();
    s.Render(*renderer);

    //draw projectiles
    m_projectileManager->Render(*renderer);

    return true;
}
```

ProjectileManager Render

```
void ProjectileManager::Render(IRenderer& renderer) {

    for (std::shared_ptr<Projectile>& projectile : m_projectiles) {
        Sprite& sprite = projectile->GetSprite();

        sprite.Render(renderer);
    }

}
```

Sprite Update/Render

```
void Sprite::Update(DX::StepTimer const & timer)
{
    if (m_cycleTextures) {

        uint64_t currentTime = Time::CurrentTimeMilliseconds();

        if (currentTime > (m_lastCycle + (uint64_t)m_cycleDelay)) {
            m_cycleId = (m_cycleId + 1) % m_textures.size();

            m_texture = m_textures[m_cycleId];

            m_lastCycle = currentTime;
        }
    }

}

void Sprite::Render(IRenderer& renderer) {
    Rendering::SpriteRenderDescription renderDescription =
        Rendering::SpriteRenderDescription(m_texture.Get(), m_vertexBuffer.GetAddressOf(), m_indexBuffer.GetAddressOf(), m_worldMatrix);

    renderer.Render(renderDescription);
}
```

SpriteRenderer Render

```
void SpriteRenderer::Render(Rendering::RenderDescription const& renderDescription)
{
    Rendering::SpriteRenderDescription const& spriteRenderDescription = dynamic_cast<Rendering::SpriteRenderDescription const&>(renderDescription);

    if (!m_loadingComplete)
    {
        return;
    }

    auto context = m_deviceResources->GetD3DDeviceContext();

    //stores the world/model for the object being rendered
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&m_constantBufferData.model, XMLoadFloat4x4(&spriteRenderDescription.m_world));


    // Prepare the constant buffer to send it to the graphics device.
    context->UpdateSubresource1(
        m_constantBuffer.Get(),
        0,
        NULL,
        &m_constantBufferData,
        0,
        0,
        0
    );

    // Each vertex is one instance of the VertexPositionColor struct.
    UINT stride = sizeof(ShaderStructures::VertexTextureCoordinates);
    UINT offset = 0;
    context->IASetVertexBuffers(
        0,
        1,
        spriteRenderDescription.m_vertexBuffer,
        &stride,
        &offset
    );

    context->IASetIndexBuffer(
        *spriteRenderDescription.m_indexBuffer,
        DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, // Each index is one 16-bit unsigned integer (short).
        0
    );

    //update texture
    context->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, m_sampleState.GetAddressOf());
    context->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &spriteRenderDescription.m_texture);

    ID3D11RasterizerState* rasterState;
    D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC wfdesc;
    ZeroMemory(&wfdesc, sizeof(D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC));
    wfdesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
    wfdesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_NONE;
    m_deviceResources->GetD3DDevice()->CreateRasterizerState(&wfdesc, &rasterState);
    context->RSSetState(rasterState);


    context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    context->IASetInputLayout(m_inputLayout.Get());

    // Attach our vertex shader.
    context->VSSetShader(
        m_vertexShader.Get(),
        nullptr,
        0
    );

    // Send the constant buffer to the graphics device.
    context->VSSetConstantBuffers1(
        0,
        1,
        m_constantBuffer.GetAddressOf(),
        nullptr,
        nullptr
    );

    // Attach our pixel shader.
    context->PSSetShader(
        m_pixelShader.Get(),
        nullptr,
        0
    );

    // Draw the objects.
    context->DrawIndexed(
        6,
        0,
        0
    );

}
```

Comment: Try showing the code you're using to update and render your sprites. Or use a profiler to identify where your program is spending a disproportionate amount of time (ie. a bottleneck) and show us that code. Also, remember that ms per frame is a more reliable metric than frames per second, since the latter is non-linear. A drop from 3000 to 500 fps looks huge but is actually just a change from 0.33 to 2 ms per frame (+1.67) - about half as much as the change from 75 to 60 fps (+3.33).

Comment: Those numbers aren't as drastic as they seem; FPS isn't a linear measure, the change from 3000FPS (0.3 milliseconds per frame) to 500 (2 milliseconds per frame) isn't as drastic as it sounds. Some of that is unavoidable (because there's some unavoidable overhead to rendering anything), but the rest may be tied up into a bottleneck that is more subtle than the FPS numbers suggest. I would strongly recommend using a profiler.

Comment: @DMGregory I have added some code for the updating/rendering I am using. I'll try using a profiler now to see if there is a problem somewhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big red flags I see after a quick look over the code you posted are

- You're using `dynamic_cast` inside your `Render` function; `dynamic_cast` has a runtime overhead and is often "smells" of a design problem. You should look at re-engineering the need for this cast. It seems to me that you can just pass `SpriteRenderDescription` in here, since `SpriteRenderer` can't render anything *else* anyhow. If `SpriteRenderer::Render` is taking the base type because it's part of some virtual interface, consider de-virtualizing that interface (I don't have enough context for your code to suggest how, unfortunately).
- You're updating the constant buffer for the sprite for every render of what appears to be every individual sprite. It also looks like you maybe have one vertex/index buffer (et cetera) per sprite. This generates a lot of overhead, whereas instead you could probably implement some kind of batching system where *multiple* sprites are contained in a single constant/vertex/index buffer (and thus a single draw call). This would reduce that overhead. Similar with the management of textures and input layout states for shaders, et cetera.
- You're doing calling `CreateRasterizerState` every time you render an individual sprite. You should only create these states once, at startup, and reference them as-needed during rendering (especially since they are exactly the same for every sprite). The runtime should de-duplicate the underlying state objects, but there's still overhead in that calculation that you can simply avoid by making the state object once.

I'd venture to guess that batching as much as you can is what's going to solve most of your performance woes. If you can only tackle one thing from the list above, I'd tackle that.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'll certainly look at all of them. The first issue you mentioned was because it is part of an interface and I didn't want to couple some other class with a specific renderer. The second issue, each sprite does have its own index/vertex buffer which after looking at it again doesn't really make sense as they are all based on a quad, which is the same indices/vertices. Is there any more code I can provide to get any further suggestions on the first problem and removing the `dynamic_cast` without removing the interface?

Comment: That's probably veering a bit off-topic for this specific question; if you posted a new question (or asked in the [chat]) I'm sure you'd get some guidance. It would help to see the interface in question, and to have an answer ready to the initial question "why is this interface virtual at all?"

Comment: Can you expand a bit on the second point where you talk about the batching? Any brief examples on how I'd go about this as the only way I've really been taught is a single draw call per object. Right now I'm rendering 40 sprites to the screen and with my current implementation it's 40 draw calls, and each object has its own buffer so 40 index/vertex buffers.

Comment: Use ``SpriteBatch`` in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Sprites-and-textures).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I will eventually be moving to use that, but I need to learn what is actually bringing down the performance as I can't use `SpriteBatch` for 3d rendering

Comment: If you poke around the site, there's a few questions addressing sprite batching techniques that may help you. Perusing the source code linked by Chuck Walbourn may also help. The basic idea is to group data for _many_ sprites (that share a texture/shader "material") into one large buffer and draw that. Depending on the size you choose for the buffer, you may ultimately need more, but you still end up with fewer buffers and draw calls than a 1:1 approach.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if **your bottleneck is the number of draw calls**, and not the number and size of sprites being drawn.

At some point I learned a heuristic that says you can execute about 3000 draw calls per frame to maintain a frame rate of 30 FPS. This limitation exists because of the *CPU overhead* imposed by DirectX and the GPU driver. In other words, even though you're only drawing a single tiny sprite per draw call, your frame rate will decline rapidly because of the overhead of setting up individual vertex buffers, index buffers, constant buffers, raster states, etc. Note that because this is a limitation in the GPU *driver* on the *CPU*, you will experience declining FPS despite having a very powerful GPU. On the other hand, it still looks like you're only calling `DrawIndexed` about 20x/frame, which leaves plenty of room for more. But I'm accustomed to being overjoyed at anything in excess of 60FPS, so I don't pay much attention to the bottlenecks in the 500FPS-3000FPS range.

If you are in fact limited by draw calls, you can fix it by rendering multiple sprites in a single draw call instead of many calls to `DrawIndexed` . (Perhaps SpriteBatch works this way, as @ChuckWalborn suggested, or try using instancing.) Another more invasive way to avoid draw call overhead is to use a low-overhead graphics API like Vulkan, Mantle, or DX 12's low level API.

The most obvious limitation when drawing a bunch of sprites is that you're limited by texture bandwidth on the GPU, but this seems implausible in your case given that you're drawing a small number of a single small sprite. Nevertheless, you can easily test for texture bandwidth bottleneck by cranking up the MIP bias on your GPU, which will force the GPU to use the highest (blurriest) MIP for all your textures, meaning it's only going to read a single texel for each texture.